# Help with RANK() Over Scalar Function - SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ranking, user-defined-functions

I have the following **Inline Table-Valued Function:**

```
SELECT   Locations.LocationId, 
         dbo.Search_GetSuitability(@SearchPreferences,
            Score.FieldA, Score.FieldB, Score.FieldC) AS OverallSuitabilityScore,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OverallSuitabilityScore) AS OverallSuitabilityRank

FROM        dbo.LocationsView Locations
INNER JOIN  dbo.LocationScores Score ON Locations.LocationId = Score.LocationId
WHERE       Locations.CityId = @LocationId
```

That `RANK()` line is giving me an error:

> Invalid column name 'OverallSuitabilityScore'.

The function `dbo.Search_GetSuitability` is a **scalar-function** which returns a `DECIMAL(8,5)`. I need to assign a rank to each row based on that value.

The only way i can get the above to work is to add the scalar function call in the `ORDER BY` part again - which is silly. I have about 5 of these scalar function calls and i need seperate `RANK()` values for each.

What can i do? Can i use a Common Table Expression (CTE) ?

Comment: Without an Order By, won't that just randomly choose 10 values?

Comment: @Thomas - there is an OrderBy in the calling stored procedure.

Comment: The RANK function will properly assign values because of the `OVER (ORDER BY...`.  The order of the result set is not defined.

Comment: thats right. i don't care about ordering for this function, it just needs to return a set of RANK values. the stored proc joins on this function and orders by the rank values. **edit:** i removed the `TOP(10)` - that was supposed to be in the calling sproc, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can't reference a column alias in the SELECT clause.  The CTE sounds good though.  Here's an example

```
WITH Score as
    (
    select Score.LocationId, Score.FieldA, Score.FieldB, Score.FieldC,
        dbo.Search_GetSuitability(@SearchPreferences,
            Score.FieldA, Score.FieldB, Score.FieldC) AS OverallSuitabilityScore
    from dbo.LocationScores
    )

SELECT   TOP(10) 
         Locations.LocationId, 
         Score.OverallSuitabilityScore,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OverallSuitabilityScore) AS OverallSuitabilityRank

FROM        dbo.LocationsView Locations
INNER JOIN  Score ON Locations.LocationId = Score.LocationId
WHERE       Locations.CityId = @LocationId
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I really need to start learning about CTE's - because i've spent 70% of my developer life on SQL Server 2000 i've missed out on all these awesome goodies. :) Accepting your answer in 45 seconds...

Answer (score 2):

An old school way of doing this is just to SUBQUERY the expression.
The CTE here only moves the subquery to the top

```
SELECT   TOP(10) LocationId, 
        OverallSuitabilityScore,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OverallSuitabilityScore) AS OverallSuitabilityRank
FROM
(
    SELECT
         Locations.LocationId, 
         dbo.Search_GetSuitability(@SearchPreferences,
             Score.FieldA, Score.FieldB, Score.FieldC) AS OverallSuitabilityScore
    FROM        dbo.LocationsView Locations
    INNER JOIN  dbo.LocationScores Score ON Locations.LocationId = Score.LocationId
    WHERE       Locations.CityId = @LocationId   
) X
```

Comment: yep, that's another option. +1